# How do you fix the warning "Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled" on Windows 10?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, windows-10, dockerfile

I have a docker-compose.yml file. When I run this, I get the warning "Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled".

Below is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    # container_name: myapp
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '52000:52000'
      # - '8080:8080'
    #   - '4300:4300'
    #   - '4301:4301'
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "redis:6379", "--", "npm", "start"]
    links:
      - redis
      - mongo
  mongo:
    # container_name: myapp-mongo
    image: 'mongo:latest'
    ports:
      - '28107:28107'
      # - '27017:27017'
  redis:
    # container_name: myapp-redis
    # restart: always
    image: 'redis:4.0.11'
    # command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
```

Below are my logs:

```
redis_1  | 1:C 24 Sep 10:21:09.224 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis_1  | 1:C 24 Sep 10:21:09.236 # Redis version=4.0.11, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis_1  | 1:C 24 Sep 10:21:09.236 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis_1  | 1:M 24 Sep 10:21:09.239 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis_1  | 1:M 24 Sep 10:21:09.239 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
redis_1  | 1:M 24 Sep 10:21:09.239 # Server initialized
mongo_1  | 2019-09-24T10:21:10.304+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
redis_1  | 1:M 24 Sep 10:21:09.239 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
redis_1  | 1:M 24 Sep 10:21:09.239 * Ready to accept connections
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.

From the error you could use `'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled'` on docker host to fix your problem.

But, I know you are on windows & cannot access hyper-v MobyLinuxVM, so you should use workaround as next:

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: 'redis:4.0.11'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    depends_on:
      - helper
    sysctls:
      - net.core.somaxconn=511
  helper:
    image: alpine
    command: sh -c "echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled"
    privileged: true
```

Above will first start a helper container which will set `never` for `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled`, as all containers will share the same kernel of host, so your redis container which start later will also benefit from this, see next execution log:

```
PS E:\abc> docker-compose up
Starting abc_helper_1 ... done
Recreating 29ea8bfaeafc_abc_redis_1 ... done
Attaching to abc_helper_1, abc_redis_1
redis_1   | 1:C 25 Sep 15:38:17.822 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis_1   | 1:C 25 Sep 15:38:17.822 # Redis version=4.0.11, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis_1   | 1:C 25 Sep 15:38:17.822 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis_1   | 1:M 25 Sep 15:38:17.822 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis_1   | 1:M 25 Sep 15:38:17.823 # Server initialized
redis_1   | 1:M 25 Sep 15:38:17.823 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
redis_1   | 1:M 25 Sep 15:38:17.823 * Ready to accept connections
```

Comment: I tried your way and I got this warning below:

`redis_1   | 1:M 25 Sep 09:44:54.152 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis_1   | 1:M 25 Sep 09:44:54.152 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
redis_1   | 1:M 25 Sep 09:44:54.153 # Server initialized
redis_1   | 1:M 25 Sep 09:44:54.153 * Ready to accept connections`

I tried to debug the above warning by using below command in my docker-compose file, but no success:

`privileged: true
    sysctls:
      net.core.somaxconn: '511'`

Comment: Your question ask for the warning `Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled`, it has been resolved, the warning you mentioned in comments is not a new warning, you can have a look for your question log, it's also in old log. Do you mean you also want to make this warning not been seen, or you mistake that above solution not fix `Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled issue`?

Comment: And if want to fix that another warning issue, you really could use sysctls, just seems you use the wrong syntax, see updated answer.

Comment: @atlne thanks for the help. The warning is gone now. My ultimate goal is to run my nodeJs application using docker. But, due to redis error, I am not able to achieve it.
When I run the command: "docker-compose up", I get the below logs and not able to resolve:  
`myapp_1   | {"message":"undefined,UserName: ,Error Text :redis client error: %s","level":"error"}  
myapp_1   | {"message":"undefined,UserName: ,Error Text :redis client error: %s","level":"error"}  
myapp_1   | {"message":"undefined,UserName: ,Error Text :redis client error: %s","level":"error"}`

Comment: What I suggest is: use a redis client to try to link the redis server in container, if it could link, then it's not redis server issue, you are encouraged to post another question & add more info related to `myapp`, e.g. Dockerfile to the new question.

Comment: This is Genius! Thanks!